# django dumpdata hangs

Tags: django, django-admin

On AWS using Postgres, I do:

```
manage.py dumpdata
```

and the server just hangs. Any suggestions about what I should look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have tons of data, dumpdata will take it's time because it's reformatting everything in JSON (or XML.)

Maybe it even tries to do everything in memory, that might be a problem.

Another tip for these problems where it's hard to pinpoint the root cause, is to add print statements into Django itself.

Comment: You are right. It wasn't hanging - it was just taking much longer than I expected.  Thanks.